# if list of objects contains value then return that object

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, object

I have a list of objects. I want to return the object that contains a particular value.

This my list:

```
my_list = [
    {
        'machine': 'abc',
        'shapes':[
            {
                'shape': 'square',
                'width': 40,
                'height': 40
            },
            {
                'shape': 'rectangle',
                'width': 30,
                'height': 40
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'machine': 'xyz',
        'shapes':[
            {
                'shape': 'square',
                'width': 40,
                'height': 40
            },
            {
                'shape': 'rectangle',
                'width': 30,
                'height': 40
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'machine': 'xyz',
        'shapes':[
            {
                'shape': '/square/',
                'width': 40,
                'height': 40
            },
            {
                'shape': 'rectangle',
                'width': 30,
                'height': 40
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want the whole list that has `'shape': '/square/'`.

I did:

```
for lst in my_list:
    # pprint(lst)
    if('xyz' in lst['machine']):
        pprint(lst['machine'])
        lst['shapes'] = [val for val in lst['shapes'] if val['shape'].startswith('/sq')]
        pprint(lst['shapes'])
```

This only returns `[{'height': 40, 'shape': '/square/', 'width': 40}]`.

Is there a way for me to get everything in that list **(Expected Result)**:

```
[
  {'height': 40, 'shape': '/square/', 'width': 40},
  {'height': 40, 'shape': 'rectangle', 'width': 30}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how:

```
my_list = [{'machine': 'abc',
            'shapes':[{'shape': 'square',
                       'width': 40,
                       'height': 40},
                      {'shape': 'rectangle',
                       'width': 30,
                       'height': 40}]},
           {'machine': 'xyz',
            'shapes':[{'shape': 'square',
                       'width': 40,
                       'height': 40},
                      {'shape': 'rectangle',
                       'width': 30,
                       'height': 40}]},
           {'machine': 'xyz',
            'shapes':[{'shape': '/square/',
                       'width': 40,
                       'height': 40},
                      {'shape': 'rectangle',
                       'width': 30,
                       'height': 40}]}]

for dct in my_list:
    if any('/square/' in d.values() for d in dct['shapes']):
        print(dct['shapes'])
```

Output:

```
[{'shape': '/square/', 'width': 40, 'height': 40},
 {'shape': 'rectangle', 'width': 30, 'height': 40}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `next` and a comprehension here as it seems you're looking for only one of the shapes in this list.

<sub>I'm using `operator.itemgetter` to reduce the extra lookups, therefore no nested loop.</sub>

```
from operator import itemgetter
get_shape, get_shapes = itemgetter('shape'), itemgetter('shapes')
next(shapes for shapes in map(get_shapes, my_list) if '/square/' in map(get_shape, shapes))
```

Result:

```
[{'shape': '/square/', 'width': 40, 'height': 40}, {'shape': 'rectangle', 'width': 30, 'height': 40}]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the minimum modifications at your code. You could keep your filter to test if an element is present and print the whole thing...

```
for lst in my_list:
    # pprint(lst)
    if('xyz' in lst['machine']):
        pprint(lst['machine'])
        if len([lst['shapes'] for val in lst['shapes'] if val['shape'].startswith('/sq')]):
            pprint(lst['shapes'])
```

Comment: Can this be done using list comprehension? if I do `lst['shapes']= [lst['shapes'] for val in lst['shapes'] if val['shape'].startswith('/sq')]` I am getting an empty array first

Comment: @nb_nb_nb Well... if i understand correctly... you could get rid of your first instructions and include them in the list comprehension operation, but this'll make it pretty messy in the end (at least that's what I think)... like `pprint([shape for lst in my_list if 'xyz' in lst['machine'] for val in lst['shapes'] if val['shape'].startswith('/sq') for shape in lst['shapes']])`

Answer (score 0):

```
my_value = "/square/"

elements = []
for element in my_list:
    for d in element['shapes']:
        if d['shape'] == my_value:
            elements.append(element)
            continue

print(elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get every dictionary on your list.

```
from pprint import pprint

# my_list

for i in my_list:
    pprint(i['shapes'][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
filter(lambda y: any([it.get('shape') == '/square/' for it in y]), map(lambda x: x['shapes'], my_list))
```